# VS 2013 $(Configuration) Macro/Variable not Recognised

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, configuration

I have a problem with my output directory not being recognised at build time.  The build output path in my VB project is set to:

..\..\bin\$(Configuration)\

Which should result in the build to ..\..\bin\Debug

Unfortunately VS is building to directory '..\..\bin\$(Configuration)'.

Anyone come across this before in VS 2013?  If so what is the solution?

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are doing it this way? Changing the configuration changes the output path automatically does it not? so For debug you would have **..\..\bin\Debug** and if you changed the configuration to release it would change the output path to **..\..\bin\Release**.

Comment: This is the entry that was in one of my DLL projects associated with the same solution, this being the case it seemed to make sense the Main application project would follow the same convention, though this is perhaps not the case from what you are saying.